# Counterexample: A collection of subsets satisfying the given property that is not locally finite.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples

This exercise comes from Lee's book on topological manifolds:

> Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is a cover of a topological space $X$ such that each element of $\mathcal{A}$ intersects only with finitely many others. If $\mathcal{A}$ is an open cover, then it's locally finite. Give an example to show that this may be false if $\mathcal{A}$ is not an open cover.

I come up with the following example. Let $D = \{ x\in \mathbb{R}^2: |x| \leq 1\}$ be the closed disk in the plane. Define $A_1 = \{ (r,\theta): 0 \leq r \leq 1 , \,  0\leq \theta\leq \pi\}$ (here I use the polar coordinates for convenience). For every $j\geq 2$, we then define
$$
 A_j = \{ (r,\theta): 0 <r \leq 1 , \, (\frac{1}{2}+ ....+\frac{1}{2^{j-1}})2\pi \leq \theta \leq (\frac{1}{2}+ ....+\frac{1}{2^{j}})2\pi \,\}.
$$
The collection $\mathcal{A} = \{ A_j\}_1^\infty$ then covers $D$. $A_1$ intersects only with $A_2$, while $A_j$ intersects only with $A_{j-1}$ and $A_{j+1}$ for each $j \geq 2$. Consider the origin $O$ of the plane. Since every open ball centered at $O$ intersects with infinite number of $A_j$s, the collection $\mathcal{A}$ is not locally finite.

I'd like to ask whether my example really serves as a counterexample, which seems right to me. Besides, Is there any simpler example? Thanks.

Comment: Consider the set of all singletons for an appropriate space (for instance, the reals).

Comment: @Ulli Why not an official answer?

Comment: @PaulFrost What's an official answer?

Comment: @KyleH. Ulli's comment gives an answer to your question (a simpler example). I suggested to write a **proper answer** which can be accepted / upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is my "official" answer:

Let $X$ be a topological space.
$\mathcal{A} := \{\{x\}: x \in X\}$ the set of all its singletons. Of course, $\mathcal{A}$ is a cover of $X$, such that each element intersects only itself. Obviously, $\mathcal{A}$ is locally finite, iff each $x \in X$ is contained in an open, finite set. Hence, if $X = \mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, $\mathcal{A}$ is not locally finite.